# Keyerror where pandas column iname is an interger

Tags: pandas

I've a df where some of the columns are intergers.

I get a key error for df['1']

KeyError: '1'
in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err

The column exists, and if I seek the name of the column by index (df.columns[10]) I get

Comment: 1 and '1' are different

Comment: Try `df[1]` or `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)`